# Разные результаты от применения схожих по смыслу утилит

Tags: valgrind

Почему получилось так, что Валгринд показывает одно количество вызова сискола write a strace другое? Да, если ходить по узлам дерева которое построил Валгринд число сисколов меняется, что видимо соответствует количеству сисколов в развернутом узле дерева. Но у меня получилось, что Валгринд отобразил число намного большее, чем стрейс. Если брать сискол write то результаты 444 vs 360 а если read, то 412 vs 417[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подопытный код ([mcve]) в студию... и точные команды запуска...

Comment: Я пропускал через эти утилиты прогу по кодированию Хаффмана с прочими велосипедами. Она немаленькая..)

Comment: На гит есть ссылка

Comment: в любом случае код для тестов стоит минимизировать, но сохранить поведение... без этого дальнейшее обсуждение ИМХО лишено смысла...